# Finding and saving the last occurrence of a string using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to find the last occurrence of a string in a plain text file (no delimiters or columns) and save its line number and the entire line in variables for later use in my script

Then I need to check if there is an occurrence of a second string after the line we just found.

I'm unsure of how to do this, I'm a scrub at bash. I'm not sure how to save results of awk in a variable, and I'm not sure of the logic i'd need to find the last occurrence of a string. Any advice/guidance would be amazing

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and output?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a script in shell that should be written entirely in awk instead. shell is an environment from which to call tools, not a tool to manipulate text - that's awk's job. Post a sample input file, expected output, and what you'd done so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Remember last line on which we saw "string_to_match", and the line itself
/string_to_match/ { last1 = NR; line=$0 }
# Remember last line on which we saw "second_string"
/second_string/ { last2 = NR }
# At the end of the file, if last2 was after last1, print it.
END { if (last2 > last1) print last2 }
```

Basically just process each line in turn and every time you find the first string update the `last1` and `line` variables.

Similarly, every time you see the first string update the `last2` variable.

When you reach the end of the file `last1` will be the last line on which you saw the first string. At  that point you can see if the second string was seen after that point.  You can also do whatever processing you need using `last1` and `line`.

Comment: the OP said string, not RE, so it'd be `index($0,"string_to_match")`, not `/string_to_match/` etc.

Comment: Ok, I have this so far. I'm assuming its okay to do in one awk `awk 'index($0,"string1") { last1 = NR; line=$0 } index($0,"string2") { last2 = NR } END { if (last1 > last2) print last1 : $last1}' inputFile`. Is there a way to output last1 and $last1 into variables? I'd like to do this in a shellscript where I can do some other things with them after the awk

Comment: yes and no but the point is you are almost certainly going about this completely the wrong way and trying to awk one-liners inside a shell script instead of simply writing a much simpler, clearer, briefer awk script.

Comment: @EdMorton I have like 6 other steps to do with the output after running that awk, including sending an an email and executing a command on a remote server...